# React native FlatList not rerendering when data prop changes to empty array

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` with a `data` prop pulling from Redux

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.arrayOfPlacesFromRedux}
          renderItem={({item}) => {.......
```

Whenever I dispatch changes to `arrayOfPlacesFromRedux`(i.e. adding or removing children), the `FlatList` rerenders....**UNLESS** I remove all children from array (i.e. make length zero).
When `arrayOfPlacesFromRedux` changes from a positive length to a length of zero, the `FlatList` does not rerender.....however all other types of changes to array do indeed cause `FlatList` to rerender

UPDATE 02/27
Below is my reducer used to update Redux `arrayOfPlacesFromRedux`

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PLACES_ARRAY:
      return {...state, arrayOfPlaces: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In the situation noted above when FlatList does not rerender.....`action.payload` is an empty array

Comment: Is `arrayOfPlacesFromRedux` always an array? If you are not sure, you can guard with `arrayOfPlacesFromRedux || []`

Comment: Tried that - didnt make a difference

Comment: try Adding extraData={this.props.arrayOfPlacesFromRedux} props to flatList

Comment: This did not work either

Comment: can you  please provide renderItem function code? Might be, It causes problem.

Comment: @jamesmurphy, Make sure that you are not mutating the data in dispatching an action.

Comment: @jamesmurphy Can you show the code you use for updating your redux state? As Vicky says, you have to be sure you are not mutating the Redux state, bc that would mess up the react rerendering.

Comment: Updated question to show reducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no rookie mistake that wasted everyones time!!
I was implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` method that was stopping Flatlist rendering :(
Thanks for all for the answers

Answer (score 0):

The question is missing some important piece of code.
React as well as Redux need arrays reference to change, meaning for a component to reRender on state change, the array references needs to change.

Live demo at https://snack.expo.dev/RrFFxfeWY

Here is the most interesting parts:

If you have a basic component as below:

```
const MyList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([
    '#FF0000',
    '#FF8000',
    '#FFFF00',
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <Text>List poping is not working</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => {
              data.pop(); // Does not work because we are not changing it's ref
            }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: item, padding: 8 }}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

The `data` need to have a new array reference as below. `data2.filter(..)` will return a new array, we are not changing the data2 base values, just creating a new array with one item less.

```
const MyList = () => {
  const [data2, setData2] = React.useState([
    '#00FFFF',
    '#0080FF',
    '#0000FF',
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <Text>List WORKING!</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={data2}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => {
              setData2(data2.filter(dataItem => dataItem !== item)) // works

              //setData2([]); // Also works
            }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: item, padding: 8 }}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

A library like [Immer.js](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) simplify the manipulation of states to mutate the object, and immer will created a new reference for you.

Comment: Ive updated my question to show the code used in the reducer.  In order to implement the solution you have recommended....how should I change the code?

Comment: Hi @jamesmurphy thanks for the update, how is the component connected to the redux state? Could you make a reproduction on https://snack.expo.dev/ ? You can use my example too.

Comment: Component is connected to Redux state by using this.props.arrayOfPlacesFromRedux for the data prop....along with mapStateToProps

Answer (score -3):

You may need to use `ListEmptyComponent`, which is a prop that comes with FlatList, [src](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#:%7E:text=Rendered%20when%20the%20list%20is%20empty.%20Can%20be%20a%20React).

Honestly, I'm not sure why it does not re-render when you update your state, or why they added a specific function/prop to render when the array is empty, but it's clear from the docs that this is what's needed.

You can do something like this:

```js
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        extraData={selectedId}
-->     ListEmptyComponent={() => <MyComponent />}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: This didnt work either